# How to make a composite function out of 2 vector fields?

Tags: vector-fields, differential, function-and-relation-composition

Ok, so currently I'm studying differential calculus on vector fields, but I feel like I'm missing some understanding on this specific topic: how do I make a composite function out of 2 vector fields ? for example:

being $f(x,y,z) = (x^2+y+z)i + (xy)j $

and $g(u,v,w) = (u+v+w)i + (w+v)j+(u*\sin(v))k $

find $h(u,v,w)$ such as:

$h(u,v,w) = f(g(u,v,w))$

OBS: That is just a simple example, please don't focus on it's answer. I'm really interested in how it is done

Comment: I hope it's prettier now ! Please tell me if anything else can help

Comment: By way of context, is $g$ to be viewed as a mapping from three-space to three-space, and we're just composing mappings? (Not sure how else to interpret the question, but it's a little strange to treat vector fields this way.)

Comment: I suppose it can be seen this way. This composites functions are supposed to help with the understanding of partial derivatives and extreme problems, so I believe it's more of a tool of problem solving, although the book explicitly says composite functions like that are already a phenomenon I should be understanding as a engineer. This entire situation makes me a bit confused.